# How to assign key:value to dict iterating over dynamic nested dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, twitter

How can I iterate over nested JSON data, extracting values, only when the key exists?

Using the Twitter API, if a tweet contains a hashtag, it's nested in tweet -> entities -> hashtags -> 0 (and this is the bit that changes) -> text.

If a tweet has more than 1 hashtag, the API creates a new key inside hastags going up from 0. So you can end up with tweet -> entities -> hashtags: {0: foo}, {1: bar}, {2: sup}, etc.

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593adcb1b27be5eb5daa7e66"),
    "created_at" : "Fri Jun 09 14:54:55 +0000 2017",
    "id" : NumberLong(873191685915906049),
    "id_str" : "873191685915906049",
    "text" : "RT @NiamhMannion_: A beautiful day in Kinvara! Really impressed by the delicious produce @kinvaramarket #FoodieHeaven URL",
    "truncated" : false,
    "entities" : {
        "hashtags" : [ 
            {
                "text" : "FoodieHeaven",
                "indices" : [ 
                    104, 
                    117
                ]
            }
        ],
        "symbols" : [],
        "user_mentions" : [ 
            {
                "screen_name" : "NiamhMannion_",
                "name" : "Niamh Mannion",
                "id" : NumberLong(2178812961),
                "id_str" : "2178812961",
                "indices" : [ 
                    3, 
                    17
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "screen_name" : "kinvaramarket",
                "name" : "KinvaraFarmersMarket",
                "id" : NumberLong(3064922836),
                "id_str" : "3064922836",
                "indices" : [ 
                    89, 
                    103
                ]
            }
        ],
        "urls" : []
    },
    "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
    "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id" : null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null,
    "user" : {
        "id" : 37690003,
        "id_str" : "37690003",
        "name" : "Gabriela Guedez H",
        "screen_name" : "GabyGuedezH",
        "location" : "Ireland",
        "description" : "Award-wining food and drinks journalist at @TheTaste_ie Passionate about wines, whiskey, rum, spirits and craft beer. WSET Certified",
        "url" : "URL",
        "entities" : {
            "url" : {
                "urls" : [ 
                    {
                        "url" : "URL",
                        "expanded_url" : "URL",
                        "display_url" : "URL",
                        "indices" : [ 
                            0, 
                            22
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description" : {
                "urls" : []
            }
        },
        "protected" : false,
        "followers_count" : 7900,
        "friends_count" : 5047,
        "listed_count" : 159,
        "created_at" : "Mon May 04 16:02:34 +0000 2009",
        "favourites_count" : 8905,
        "utc_offset" : 3600,
        "time_zone" : "Dublin",
        "geo_enabled" : true,
        "verified" : false,
        "statuses_count" : 12727,
        "lang" : "en",
        "contributors_enabled" : false,
        "is_translator" : false,
        "is_translation_enabled" : false,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "5ED4DC",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "95E8EC",
        "profile_text_color" : "3C3940",
        "profile_use_background_image" : true,
        "has_extended_profile" : false,
        "default_profile" : false,
        "default_profile_image" : false,
        "following" : true,
        "follow_request_sent" : false,
        "notifications" : false,
        "translator_type" : "none"
    },
    "geo" : null,
    "coordinates" : null,
    "place" : null,
    "contributors" : null,
    "is_quote_status" : false,
    "retweet_count" : 4,
    "favorite_count" : 14,
    "favorited" : true,
    "retweeted" : true,
    "possibly_sensitive" : false,
    "lang" : "en",
    "has_hashtags" : false,
    "is_retweet" : false
}`

I want to take all existing hashtags, extract the text and store it in my new dictionary.

```
for tweet in tweets:
    thistweet = {
        'text': tweet.text,
        'created_at': str(tweet.created_at),
        'retweet_count': tweet.retweet_count,
        'favorite_count': tweet.favorite_count,
        'geo': tweet.geo,
        'coordinates': tweet.coordinates
    }
    for i in tweet[entities][hashtags][i]:
        thistweet = thistweet.update({'hashtag'[i]: tweet.entities.hashtags.i.text})
```

That bit of code doesn't work. I'm getting 'dict' object has no attribute 'hashtags'.

I'm not entirely sure how to start trying to fix this issue to be honest.

Comment: print the value of tweet variable and check if hashtag property exist in every entities property

Comment: @ArpitSolanki the hashtags.entities always exists, even if there are no hashtags, it's just empty:

"entities" : { "hashtags" : [ ] }

Comment: It should definitely raise a key error. Since your hashtags is a empty array it won't find anything like i.text in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for tweet in tweets:
    thistweet = {
        'text': tweet.text,
        'created_at': str(tweet.created_at),
        'retweet_count': tweet.retweet_count,
        'favorite_count': tweet.favorite_count,
        'geo': tweet.geo,
        'coordinates': tweet.coordinates,
        'hashtags':{}
    }
    for index, item in enumerate(tweet.entities.hashtags):
        try:
            thistweet = thistweet['hashtags'].update({item:tweet.entities.hashtags[index]['text']})
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: That didn't work, I'm getting an error on the line after try:, I'm not familiar with item:... perhaps it's that?

Comment: 'Status' object is not subscriptable on line "for item in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:"

Comment: Could you please post the models??

Comment: I posted a sample JSON tweet in the main body, it's too long for a comment.